# ESXi and ghettoVCM - rotate weekly backups to (2) different drives

Tags: linux, backup, vmware, symbolic-link

I am using ghettoVCB to perform VM snapshot backups on an ESXi server.  ghettoVCB has a config file that stores parameters for performing the backup.  One of the parameters is the destination path, where the backup files will be placed.  What I would like to do is rotate the backups between two drives.  So if this week the backups are stored on volume2, then next week the backups will be stored on volume3, the following week stored back on volume2 and so on.  I figured this could be done with symbolic links, place the symbolic link in the ghettoVCB.conf file and use a shell script to create\update the symbolic link to point to the next folder. Can anyone provide a shell script that could perform this type of symbolic link rotation?